# Pygame loop only renders final frame/move

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, pygame, tflearn

I am referencing a tutorial for a snake AI game using Tensorflow and pygame.

Reference: https://github.com/tolotrasam/snakegame_ai_tensorflow/tree/master/dist

For the "some random games first" and "evaluate" methods, I want to display the entire game, instead of just the final frame. For example: in the player.py code, the "some random games first" method only displays the final step frame.  I want to render each frame of each game played. How would this be done?

Also, how would I use this code to display the the "trained" model, such as the saved data in the saved.py file generated?

Any help would be appreciated.

Reference Code:

```py
LR = 1e-3
goal_steps = 300
score_requirement = 50
initial_games = 5000

def some_random_games_first():
    # Each of these is its own game.
    for episode in range(10):

        env = game()
        env.reset()
        first = True
        for _ in range(goal_steps):

            # action = random.randrange(0, 3)
            action = random.randrange(0, 3)
            # action = 2

            if first:
                first = False
                action = 2

            # do it! render the previous view
            env.render()
            observation, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
            a = 0
            if done: break
```

Snake game can be found in the GitHub link, don't want to paste that entire code.

Render method:

```py
def render(self):
        # score
        d = self.screen.blit(self.bg, SCORE_POS, pygame.Rect(SCORE_POS, (50, 100)))
        f = pygame.font.Font(None, 12)
        scoreimage = f.render(SCORE_PREFIX + str(self.currentscore), True, SCORE_COLOR)
        d2 = self.screen.blit(scoreimage, SCORE_POS)

        # drawing
        dirty = self.all.draw(self.screen)
        dirty.append(d)
        dirty.append(d2)

        # updating screen
        pygame.display.update(dirty)

        # waiting
        self.clock.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: as for me this code should display every frame. You may try to slow down it using smaller `FPS` (frame per seconds) - ie. `FPS = 1`

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work, when running Player.py in the git link it only displays the final frame, or the last goal step that's is set (300).

Comment: I see all frames on Linux Mint 19.1 / Python 3.6 / PyGame 1.9.4 / Tensoflow 1.10 / tflearn ?latest?

Comment: @furas you see more than 10 renders? interesting. Not sure why I'm not, I seem to be updated with everything. You see all the snake moves for each game?

Comment: I see this https://youtu.be/rtJs0rUfSWk

Comment: that's exactly what I want haha, I see this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zj99MyXjCBI   Any idea what's going on? Pygame 1.9.5, Python 3.7, Tensorflow 1.13.1, tflearn 0.3.2, Mac terminal @furas

Comment: first I tried with Python 3.7 but I get system error "illegal instruction" after first frame. I found that there is no tensorflow for Python 3.7 so I use Python 3.6 (I still have it). And I uninstall tensorflow and tflean and install again (version without GPU).

Comment: bigger video - with terminal in background - https://youtu.be/Xge6Nl_0Yj8 It displays frames at start, next it makes calculations and after 3 minutes it displays frames again.

Comment: I reverted back to python 3.6.5, ran again and still get the same output as in my youtube video above. I tried reducing the frame rate, adding sleeps between steps etc and nothing seems to help. Can't get it to display properly. Never got the error you were talking about though.

Comment: I have no idea. I even update PyGame to 1.9.5 and it works correclty We uses different system - Mac & Linux - and it can be the problem. For me problem can be in PyGame. Maybe in Google you can find some information about problems with PyGame on Mac. or maybe: I see Snake.py uses `pygame.display.update(dirty)` which updates only part of screen in PyGame. Using `pygame.display.flip()` it should update full screen in PyGame. Maybe it can help.

Comment: @Michael This code does not process events. Just try adding `pygame.event.get()` before calling `pygame.display.update(...)`.